# Finding $a$ given 2 linear equations with 2 other constants b and c

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to find the value of $a$ in the given the equations:

$x_1 + x_2 = b$ and $2x_1 + ax_2 = c$ considering there are also 2 extra constants $b , c$ that belong to $\Bbb{R}$.

I fall short when I start to compute for a, giving $a = 1 - (b - c)x_2$

But I can't get rid of $x_2$ since I have to find $a$. Any help?

Comment: This is not clear.  What are you given and what do you want to find?

Comment: sorry, I confused the question, I have to find "a" given 2 equations that has 2 extra constants b and c. "a" is the goal.

Comment: Your equations appear to have $5$ unknowns, namely $\{x_1,x_2,a,b,c\}$.  Presumably, some of these are meant to be given while your job wil be to find the others, yes?

Comment: The question only says to find all $a$ in $R$ domain such that those equations are satisfied and has unique solutions for any given $b$ and $c$ in $R$ domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
x_1 + x_2 = b\\
2x_1 + ax_2 = c\\
\end{cases}
$$
The matrix of the coefficients is
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
According to Cramer's rule, the system has one and only one solution if $\det A\ne 0$

$\det A=a-2\ne 0\to a\ne 2$

Thus the system has one unique solution if $a\ne 2$.